# Cordova app doesn't install on android emulator

Tags: cordova, android-emulator

I'm making a simple HelloWorld app with Cordova (following [the guide on the Cordova website](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#test-the-app)) however when I run it with an Android SDK emulator it doesn't install and is not visible from the app menu.

Here is the output when `cordova emulate android` is entered:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_23_x86
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: device fd:680

HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed

creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

The emulator then boots up and brings me to the home screen but the app is nowhere to be found.
There are no build errors and the android requirements are all present. The app also runs perfectly fine in browser. My Path system variable points correctly to ../sdk/platform-tools and ../sdk/tools as well.

The research I have done shows people with outputs that say things like:

```
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

But none of this is present in my output.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.